# filter option in form control select dropdown

Tags: c#, reactjs, react-redux, react-bootstrap

I am new to reactJs. I am using react-bootstrap and am using <Form.Control as = 'select'> to show options from my database.

The code is here below:

```
<Form.Group controlID="Department">
    <Form.Label>
        Department
    </Form.Label>

    <Form.Control as = 'select'>
        {this.state.deps.map(dep =>
        <option key={dep.DepartmentID}>{dep.DepartmentName}</option>
        )}
    </Form.Control>

</Form.Group>
```

I was wondering can I add a filter option at the top where I can search for my elements in react-bootstrap. If so please help with examples

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in a Class Component(but the idea is similar for a function component):

```
   GetFilteredOptions() {
        
            return this.state.deps.filter(dep => dep.DepartmentName.length > 6).map(dep =>
            <option key={dep.DepartmentID}>{dep.DepartmentName}</option>
            );    
        }
    
    
   render() {
        return ( <Form.Group controlID="Department">
        <Form.Label>
            Department
        </Form.Label>
    
        <Form.Control as = 'select'>
            {this.GetFilteredOptions()}
        </Form.Control>
    
    </Form.Group>);
}
```

I usually create a method to abstract this complexity just so that I can "decouple it" from the "html/TSX/JSX" part.

The idea is that in this case I am using only the items which have a department name with a length greater than 6 characters.... So you can just replace that condition with whatever condition you want.

Remeber that in a function component things might look a bit different.

But without see the complete component code it's hard to say.